# Why does the current photo in my photo carousel disappear when I select the next or previous photo? [Next/React]

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, tailwind-css, carousel, next.js14

I built a photo carousel with Next.js 14/App Router. It's almost complete but I can't figure out why the current photo (the one photo that should be displayed) disappears when I move to another photo.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/marksatin1/pen/jORbKYG) shows the bad functionality I am trying to fix. Choose next and previous photos with arrow keys.

My gut tells me this has something to do with the way I am updating my current and prev photos in my useReducer() hook but I just can't figure out how to fix it. Have looked for solutions on SO, using Copilot, and general Google searches and still stuck.

Any ideas on moving forward? Thanks!

*I know reducer functions are traditionally defined outside of the component, but mine needs access to the photos prop and I didn't want to pass all the photos every time I dispatch an action.

*The "hidden" class on the Image classname is Tailwind's version of "display: none". It is not the same as adding the "hidden" prop to the Image element.

```
function GalleryCarousel({ photos }) {
  const [navStates, dispatch] = useReducer(galleryNavReducer, {
    current: 0,
    prev: photos.length - 1,
    currentAnimation: "",
    prevAnimation: "",
  });
  const mainRef = useRef(null);

// Focus to <main> when component mounts
useEffect(() => {
  mainRef.current?.focus();
}, []);

function galleryNavReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "PREV":
      return {
        current: state.current === 0 ? photos.length - 1 : state.current - 1,
        prev: state.current,
        currentAnimation: "rotate-out-left",
        prevAnimation: "rotate-in-right",
      };
    case "NEXT":
      return {
        current: state.current === photos.length - 1 ? 0 : state.current + 1,
        prev: state.current,
        currentAnimation: "rotate-out-right",
        prevAnimation: "rotate-in-left",
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

function handleKeyDown(e: KeyboardEvent) {
  switch (e.key) {
    case "ArrowLeft":
      dispatch({ type: "PREV" });
      break;
    case "ArrowRight":
      dispatch({ type: "NEXT" });
      break;
    default:
      console.log("Some other key was pressed.");
  }
}

return (
  <main
    tabIndex={0} onKeyDown={handleKeyDown} ref={mainRef}
    className="p-4 outline-none w-full h-full flex items-center justify-center"
  >
    <div className="relative w-full h-full flex items-center justify-center">
      {photos.map((p, i) => {
        return (
          <Image
            key={p.id}
            src={p.url}
            width={p.width}
            height={p.height}
            alt={p.description}
            className={`object-contain layout-responsive w-[200px] max-h-full max-w-full ${
            i === navStates.current
              ? `${navStates.currentAnimation} block`
              : i === navStates.prev
              ? `${navStates.prevAnimation} hidden`
              : "hidden"
          }`}
            priority={i === 0}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  </main>
);
```

}